# How to access my website using https 443 port

Tags: ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt, certbot, ubuntu-22.04

I have an Ec2 with Ubuntu 22.04 version running my node.js app. I have installed nginx server for reverse proxy which is working fine. I have bought a domain from GoDaddy. Website Hosted on server on Ec2 instance. I wanted to secure my website with SSL certificate. I have use Let's Encrypt, Certbot for SSL certificate. Since I don't have Cpanel access to my website in GoDaddy I have to manually install certbot. I have successfully installed SSL certificate on my instance.

I have also used --manual-auth-hook for auto renewal of certificate. I have use API keys to connect with --manual-auth-hook. I have used OpenSSL commands. I am unable to access my website through https port. When I am type: `sudo netstat -tunlp`  command. I can't see port 443 on the servers.

Comment: my first thought is that something is wrong with nginx, maybe its not listening to port 443. second thought it could be something with a security group on Ec2

Comment: if you are not seeing port 443 when you run netstat on the instance, then you can be sure that the port is indeed not being opened.  So the problem must be somewhere with how you have configured nginx.  If you see a port 80 but no 443, then nginx is running but not creating the ssl service.  What did you miss from e.g. these instructions: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html ?  Also, did you make your new profile active in nginx by creating the necessary symlinks?

Comment: @GreenChicken, it is not listening to port 443. you are right. Should I configure the nginx configure file?

Comment: @BillHuneke, I have not configured nginx file. I was in an impression that the instance is on the front of everything, meaning the user connects the instance first. Now I understood the proxy server is in front and I have to configure nginx file. Will this resource (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) be enough for the configuration?

Comment: yeah that seems about right, good luck with the configuration. hope we helped